Why is this mark wrong?
I'm learning tcl.
I wrote a code.
test.tcl
set design C
set Z 0
if {${design} == "A"} {
    set Z 5
} elseif {${design} == "B"} {
    set Z 10
#} elseif {${design} == "C"} {
#    set Z 15
} else {
    set Z 20
}

puts "Z = ${Z}"


then run:
tclsh test.tcl
why I got the response:
Z = 0
instead of:
Z = 20
Can't I mark like this?

You have edited your question to fix the syntax errors that caused the problem — invalidating the answer(s) given below

The edited question is the question I originally wanted to ask.

It is a weirdness about the way Tcl works. See Why can I not place unmatched braces in Tcl comments

You can call it weird. I call it consistent. :-)

In 8.7/9.0, you can also put comments inside expressions. But this question and answer will still hold; # will never be a fully preprocessed comment because Tcl doesn't work that way. (It means that Critcl can embed C inside Tcl much more easily...)

Quirky? Eccentric? Unconventional? Tcl is not your run of the mill language. It is waaaay cooler than your usual state-machine EBNF grammar parsing beasts like C and Pascal.

Tcl syntax is very straight-forward. Each command consists of a command name and zero or more arguments. In Tcl, the if command is like any other command. It is not treated special in any way. So, the Tcl interpreter takes your command and splits it into the command name (if) and the following list of arguments (whitespace reformatted for clarity):

{${design} == "A"}
{set Z 5}
elseif
{${design} == "B"}
{set Z 10 ;#}
elseif
{${design} == "C"}
{# set Z 15}
else
{set Z 20}

The if command evaluates the first argument. It is 'false', so it skips the second argument. With the third argument being "elseif", it then checks the 4th argument. Continuing like this it eventually comes across argument #7, the {${design} == "C"} condition. This is not affected by the "#" inside argument #5. With $design actually having the value "C", this condition evaluates to 'true', causing argument #8 to be chosen as the body part to be executed. That argument has one line, starting with a "#", so it is treated as a comment. Now the if command has completed its job and Z remains unchanged.

Actually, the {} are not part of the argument. I just kept them as a grouping indication.

So I can understand it this way?
The tcl interpreter will first match curly braces to group them, and then ignore command lines starting with #.

Sort of. The interpreter makes no assumptions about what commands will do with their arguments. The if command happens to evaluate some of them as code again. In that case, lines starting with # are comments. Other commands may assign different meaning to arguments starting with #. Like uplevel, for example.
